# Gtk buttons over a Gtk drawing area

Tags: c, gtk, drawing, area

i' working with Gtk developing some app. I must put some buttons over a map. I'm drawing the map on a GtkDrawingarea, but i'm not able to put buttons over it. 
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions:

1. Put both the drawing area and the buttons inside a `GtkFixed` container. Probably not the best solution, because `GtkFixed` has no way of controlling the z-ordering (other than the order in which you add the widgets to it?)
2. Instead of using `GtkDrawingArea`, use a canvas widget that can include other widgets, such as [`GooCanvas`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/goocanvas/unstable/).

Comment: Thanks, but i can use only Gtk, no other library.

Comment: I thought of something else. If `GtkFixed` doesn't work then you might consider writing your own widget that inherits from the `GtkDrawingArea` class.

Answer (score 0):

Why no other library? Any specific reason?

There is a library for **exactly** what you want

http://geocanvas.sourceforge.net/