# GtkButton covered by GtkDrawingArea

Tags: c, gtk

I'm trying to place a button over a GtkDrawingArea in C (GUI is generated from a glade file).  In Glade I placed both the GtkDrawingArea and the GtkButton into a GtkFixed container.  I can click where the button is supposed to be and the buttons "clicked" event handler is successfully called, but the button is hidden behind the GtkDrawingArea.  Within the "expose-event" handler for the Drawing Area I have this:

```
gboolean on_drawArea_expose_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *expose, gpointer data)
{
   // draw on drawingArea
   gdk_window_restack( button->window, widget->window, TRUE);
   return FALSE;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
gdk_window_restack: assertion 'gdk_window_is_toplevel (GDK_WINDOW_OBJECT (sibling)' failed
```

I tried:

```
gdk_window_raise( button->window);
```

As well instead of restack, that didn't throw any errors but it didn't work either.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: What version of gtk are you using gtk+-2.0 or gtk+-3.0? And do you want to change the appearance of the button with the DrawingArea or do you really want to put a button inside your drawing, that isn't clear to me.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that it's Gtk+-2.0.  I was trying to "overlay" the button on top of the GtkDrawingArea.  I'm considering just drawing what looks like a button in the DrawingArea in the same coordinates that the actual Gtkbutton exists.  I read this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297859/gtk-buttons-over-a-gtk-drawing-area, so I was trying out the suggestion they made.

Comment: I'd like to know why it thinks my GtkDrawingArea is a toplevel gdkwindow.

Comment: The error's you're getting are because the assertion "window is toplevel" FAILED, ie. the function expected a toplevel window, which it wasn't. The functions you're trying to use look very much like window manager ones to me (manipulating stacking order of windows, raising them etc., concepts which do not apply between widget windows).

Comment: Thanks Ancurio, I had misunderstood what the gdk_window_raise() function did.  It would be nice if they had the same concept for widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up drawing the button manually within the DrawingArea in the same location the GtkButton widget is located.

```
 {
 // within expose event handler
 // draw desired image onto GdkPixmap
 // code to draw pix map goes here
 // check to see if GtkButton exists
 if( button != NULL ) 
 {
     GdkGC *buttonGC = gdk_gc_new( myPixmap );
     PangoLayout *buttonLayout =          gtk_widget_create_pango_layout( button, "press me");
     gdk_draw_layout( myPixmap, buttonGC, button->allocation.x, button->allocation.y, buttonLayout);
  }

 gdk_draw_drawable ( myparameters, ...);
 // clean up variables
return;
}
```